# How to parse data into .csv?

Tags: python, pandas

I have got an a list:

```
[{'name': 'WEB-Разработчик/программист (SEO-правки)', 'description': 'Hastra Agency ищет разработчика с опытом работы с связи с ростом отдела SEO-продвижения. Требуемый о...', 'key_skills': ['HTML', 'CSS', 'MySQL', 'PHP', 'SEO'], 'employer': 'Hastra Agency', 'salary': 'None - 60000 RUR', 'area': 'Москва', 'published_at': '2022-12-12', 'alternate_url': 'https://hh.ru/vacancy/73732873'}, {'name': 'Веб-разработчик golang, react, vue, nuxt, angular, websockets', 'description': 'Обязанности: Стек: react, vue, nuxt, angular, websockets, golang Поддержка текущего проекта с сущест...', 'key_skills': [], 'employer': 'МегаСео', 'salary': '150000 - None RUR', 'area': 'Москва', 'published_at': '2022-12-12', 'alternate_url': 'https://hh.ru/vacancy/73705217'}, ....., ......
```

array is with 10 list's
How can i make it into table? csv file?
columns - name, description, key_skills, ....
rows - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ...

Comment: Can you show the issue in your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
import pandas as pd
d = [{'name': 'WEB-Разработчик/программист (SEO-правки)', 'description': 'Hastra Agency ищет разработчика с опытом работы с связи с ростом отдела SEO-продвижения. Требуемый о...', 'key_skills': ['HTML', 'CSS', 'MySQL', 'PHP', 'SEO'], 'employer': 'Hastra Agency', 'salary': 'None - 60000 RUR', 'area': 'Москва', 'published_at': '2022-12-12', 'alternate_url': 'https://hh.ru/vacancy/73732873'}, {'name': 'Веб-разработчик golang, react, vue, nuxt, angular, websockets', 'description': 'Обязанности: Стек: react, vue, nuxt, angular, websockets, golang Поддержка текущего проекта с сущест...', 'key_skills': [], 'employer': 'МегаСео', 'salary': '150000 - None RUR', 'area': 'Москва', 'published_at': '2022-12-12', 'alternate_url': 'https://hh.ru/vacancy/73705217'}]

pd.DataFrame(d)

                                                           name                                                                                              description                    key_skills       employer             salary    area published_at                   alternate_url
0                       WEB-Разработчик/программист (SEO-правки)  Hastra Agency ищет разработчика с опытом работы с связи с ростом отдела SEO-продвижения. Требуемый о...  [HTML, CSS, MySQL, PHP, SEO]  Hastra Agency   None - 60000 RUR  Москва   2022-12-12  https://hh.ru/vacancy/73732873
1  Веб-разработчик golang, react, vue, nuxt, angular, websockets  Обязанности: Стек: react, vue, nuxt, angular, websockets, golang Поддержка текущего проекта с сущест...                            []        МегаСео  150000 - None RUR  Москва   2022-12-12  https://hh.ru/vacancy/73705217
```